# docker swarm - Leader(Manager) Node service endpoint and load balancing

Tags: web-services, docker, load-balancing, docker-swarm

docker swarm - Leader(Manager) Node service endpoint and load balancing.
Have two Queries related to Web service application deployment in docker swarm.

1. We have exposed the service endpoint to our customer as :
   http://server1:8080/Application/Service
   where server1 is our Leader(Manager) in our swarm cluster.This acts as our load balancer link also.
   But what happens to the service endpoint, when server1(Leader) goes down.
   As per Swarm, out of the other two more managers, one will be selected as Leader.
   Let us assume that server2 becomes the Leader.
   But does that mean that the previous server1 service endpoint will not work and it needs to get changed to:
   http://**server2**:8080/Application/Service and we need to shared this new URL to our consumers?
   If the URL gets changed, then its really very challenging.If not how does the previous server1 endpoint work,eventhough the server1 is down as a leader.?
2. In our current 10 nodes Swarm cluster, eventhough the service is deployed on all the 10 Servers, the service is working via only the Leader server endpoint:
   http://server1:8080/Application/Service
   where server1 is our Leader(Manager) in our swarm cluster.This acts as our load balancer link and shared with consumers.

All the individual endpoint on all the other servers doesn't work. Is this expected behavior in Swarm, that all traffic will go via the leader endpoint?

- Leader(Manager):server1  -> Works:
  http://server1:8080/Application/Service
- Other Managers: server2 and server3  -> Don't work:
  http://server2:8080/Application/Service
  http://server3:8080/Application/Service
- Workers: All other 7 servers/nodes -> Don't work:
  http://server4:8080/Application/Service
  http://server5:8080/Application/Service
  .....................

The docker swarm details are provided below:
Docker version: 1.12.1

> Swarm Structure:
>   - Leader(Manager):server1
>   - Other Managers: server2 and server3
>   - Workers: All other 7 servers/nodes
>
> Application/Service endpoint:

http://server1:8080/Application/Service
The above endpoint has been shared with our clients, so act as the load balancing endpoint.

$ sudo docker node ls

```html
ID                           HOSTNAME      STATUS  AVAILABILITY  MANAGER STATUS
0415czstge3vibxh55kwnywyd    server6  Ready   Active
2keplduit5vaycpwzv9419gh7    server4  Ready   Active
2r5e2ye9jhgko29s5bv7rolxq    server3  Ready   Active        Reachable
5btrbs5qkrlr50uiip6n0y260    server9  Ready   Active
7aqpnf79tv7aj1j5gqsmqph7x    server10  Ready   Active
856fyn6rdv9ypfz8o2jdsuj7p    server2  Ready   Active        Reachable
a1gcuucxuuupg9gleu9miz7uk    server5  Ready   Active
a2uyjjhh7phm3wei2e1ydsc4o    server7  Ready   Active
bm7ztqyrbt7noak6lerfmcs3j *  server1  Ready   Active        Leader
dwto8iizy8li46b7u6v9e4qk1    server8  Ready   Active
```